# How to Draw Route Received From MapQuestApi in nutiteq Map?

Tags: android, nutiteq

i have some problems creating route directionns on the nutiteq map from MapQuestApi, i Know how to Receive the Information needed

```
@Override
        public void onSuccess(RouteResponse routeResponse) {
            clearButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(showItineraryButton.getVisibility()==View.GONE &&
                    showMapButton.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                showItineraryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


            createRouteButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

but i dont know how to use them to create route lines on them nutiteq map, and appearantly its demo sample doesnt say any thing, it has a RouteActivity Interface which does not exists any where in the Sample Codes, if any one has done this , can some one please show me how can i "draw" the route points using received information ? i would really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **RouteActivity** is in separate project [AdvancedLayers](https://github.com/nutiteq/advancedlayers/).

From MapQuestRouteActivity.java in **AdvancedMap3D** project you can find method `public void routeResult(Route route)` which is called from MapQuestDirections.java (source is also in *AdvancedLayers*). The **MapQuestDirections** has already parsed routing result and created a line (which is part of the *Route*) which can be added to the map.